# Zooming 2d game camera makes it move from the origin (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, game-engine

These two snippets are the culprits:

```
function tr(){
    ctx.translate(0-cameraX,0-cameraY);
    ctx.scale(zoom,zoom);
}


function uiPosToWorldPos(pos){
    return [(pos[0] + cameraX) / zoom,(pos[1] + cameraY) / zoom];
}
```

What I am doing is moving my world opposite of my camera to create a scrolling/parallax world (fairly standard.) This is all good and well until I add zooming of the camera. I am having trouble finding a way to factor in the zoom to the above functions without this one problem: The farther my camera is from (0,0) and the lower zoom (zooming out) the farther my camera tends to move away from the origin.

I want to be able to zoom in and out cleanly wherever I am so that the same point in the world will remain center camera regardless of zoom. The 2nd function is necessary to determine where my mouse is on the world and also so I can set my bounds and only draw the items that are on my screen.

Comment: If I were to translate to the object first it wouldn't affect where the object is drawn just the size of it.

Answer (score 0):

You calculate your scale coefficient and then multiples it with your object position.